# Add a custom variable to an existing block

Tags: blocks, hooks, 9

Is there a way to alter the render array of an existing block?
I want to do it for a commerce block (cart block) but the question remains for any core or contrib module block.

When a block uses a custom #theme for it's block, is there a way to alter the definition?

Let's say the module defines the following theme :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function commerce_cart_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'commerce_cart_block' => [
      'variables' => [
        'icon' => NULL,
        'count' => NULL,
        'count_text' => '',
        'content' => NULL,
        'url' => NULL,
        'links' => [],
      ],
    ],
  ];
}
```

and the block uses `'#theme' => 'commerce_cart_block'` as it's build render array.

I'd like to know if there's a way to add a new custom variable to commerce_cart_block in a hook somewhere.

I tried to rewrite the commerce-cart-block.html.twig in my theme and add a new variable in it and I'd set my variable in THEME_preprocess_block__commerce_cart(), but it doesnt work.

I also tried to [alter the block's content with HOOK_block_view_alter in a module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/215820/alter-block-content), but it also didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with [hook_preprocess_HOOK](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/9.0.x) and the all caps `HOOK` part refers to the array key in `hook_theme()`.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_commerce_cart_block(&$variables) {
  // Adds a custom variable
  $variables['hello_world'] = 'Hello World';
}
```

BTW, this hook can be used either in a custom theme or custom module.

and in **commerce-cart-block.html.twig**

```
{{ hello_world }}
```

should print "Hello World".

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks you